# Custom fields in chekcout

Tags: magento2

I've added a custom input field as a new step in the checkout but now I'm struggling to find the correct way to do some order processing in the back end.
The end goal is to apply a discount to products in the cart based on the input (this isn't a discount code so the standard Magento method for that won't help, I don't think).
Essentially, after entering a value in a new step of the checkout, how do I access that value again?